# how to a local server on hyer and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to open a by following an instructor online, but whenever she opens the `localhost:3000` she gets an output.

But I am **not** getting anything it is showing, check your `internet connection` and even in `Hyper` it is giving some error when I try to type `node server.js` please help me.

[image]

I have tried changing the browser changing the code a few times but I was unable to figure out if it was a code problem or some linux error

Comment: Try this ``app.listen(3000, function() {console.log("Server running....")})`` , your code is wrong, as  you are passing a parameter to callback ``function ({console.log()})`` which is wrong..   For reference check this code snippet  [Express app.listen()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-app-listen-function/#:~:text=const%20express%20%3D%20require(%27express%27)%3B,%7D)